# MySql: designing a table of nearby stations

Tags: mysql

I have a table of stations that are scattered throughout the world.  It looks something like this:

```
+--------+------------+-------+-----------+
|   ID   |    NAME    |  LAT  |    LON    |
+--------+------------+-------+-----------+
| 104326 | BERWINDALE | 40.8  | -78.6     |
| 104406 | GRAMPIAN   | 40.9  | -78.7     |
| 121788 | COALPORT   | 40.75 | -78.53333 |
+--------+------------+-------+-----------+
```

For each station *S* in my table, I have a list of stations described by ID,LAT,LON that are considered to be nearby to *S*.  For a station in New York, the list of nearby stations would be large, at least 50 stations long.  But for a station in Timbuktu, the list of nearby stations may only contain 1 or 2 elements, or be empty.

How can I design this "neighboring stations table" considering the fact that I do not know how many neighbors are associated to a given station?  I have heard about things like normalization, but as a MySql noob, I need a bit of a detailed walkthrough.

Comment: Why do you need a separate table for this in the first place?

Comment: I could not think of any other way to do it.

Comment: You don't create a table for this. You create a table of all stations, then write a query to select TOP n nearest stations for given station or a query to find nearest stations within y miles.

Comment: This doesn't quite work as not all stations are eligible to be "neighbors" based solely on distance.  It depends on their reporting practices, their expected number of reports per day, etc., which is why we have this exact list to begin with.

Comment: I am still not clear on how do you define your *nearby locations*.  As per your sample data it looks like your nearby locations are based on nearby latitudes and longitudes. Could you give a more specific example?

Comment: We have a prepared list that gives the nearby locations for each station (these stations are global, some of them are bogus, or don't give the info we need, we want to run linear regression between neighboring stations, etc, so that purely basing it on distance doesn't work).  If the station is in the list, it is considered nearby.

Comment: Normally this would be more suited to be written as a MySQL function rather than a table. However I'm not sure if it's feasible for you to write a linear regression function in MySQL. If it's not then just make a table "Neighbours ( Station_id, Neighbour_id )" and populate it with station, neighbouring station pairs.

Comment: When you say list, where does this list come from?

Comment: so create a mapping table. one that stores the station id and neighboring station ids and store all stations in the station table

Answer (score 0):

you want to normalize the data so that your station table stores stations only

```
+--------+------------+-------+-----------+
|   ID   |    NAME    |  LAT  |    LON    |
+--------+------------+-------+-----------+
| 104326 | BERWINDALE | 40.8  | -78.6     |
| 104406 | GRAMPIAN   | 40.9  | -78.7     |
| 121788 | COALPORT   | 40.75 | -78.53333 |
+--------+------------+-------+-----------+
```

so with this table you can then create a map table that has a row for each neighbor per station.

```
+--------+----------------+-----------------+
|   ID   |   STATION_ID   |   NEIGHBOR_ID   |
+--------+----------------+-----------------+
|    1   |     104326     |     104406      |
|    2   |     104326     |     121788      |
+--------+----------------+-----------------+
```

in this simple example it would say GRAMPIAN and COALPORT are neighbors of BERWINDALE

to pull out neighbors you can do something like this.

```
SELECT s.name as central_station, n.name as neighboring_stations
FROM stations s
JOIN neighbors n ON n.neighbor_id = s.id
WHERE n.station_id = 104326
```